# Angujar 1.3 can't if data change with $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm doing a web page with Angular.js in which I show data in a table and the user can edit. Whenever the data changes, I need run a javascript function, so my idea is to use `$scope$ watch`. My problems is, the data change but `$scope$ watch` don't run.

This is a lite of my code (app.js)

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
  $scope.datos = [{x:1, y:2},
                {x:3, y:5},
                {x:2, y:8}];

  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,    // show first page
    count: 20,   // count per page
    }, {
      total: $scope.datos.length, // length of data
      getData: function($defer, params) {
              $defer.resolve($scope.datos);
      }
  });
  // add new line
  this.addLine = function() {
    $scope.datos.push({
      x: null,
      y: null,
    });
  };
  //delete data
  this.deleteLine = function(index){
    $scope.datos.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.updated = -1;
  $scope.$watch('datos', function(){
        $scope.updated++;
    });

});
```

What I do wrong? This is the best from to see is the data change?
Tanks.

Comment: try use $watchCollection instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the object equality flag so it doesn't use reference equality:

```
  $scope.$watch('datos', function(){
      $scope.updated++;
  }, true);
```

Or, use `$watchCollection` as Deuterium suggests:

```
  $scope.$watchCollection('datos', function(){
      $scope.updated++;
  });
```